# Как поднять nginx контейнер с данными из другого контейнера

Tags: nginx, docker, pytest

Я только начал разбираться с Докером и никак не могу понять как мне правильно поступить. Мне нужно прогнать тесты (Pytest) в контейнере, после этого формируется репорт index.html. Этот репорт мне нужно поднять nginx. Понимаю что нужно использовать volume но как не понимаю. Подскажите плз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае наиболее подходящим на мой взгляд решением будет использование [multi-stage билда](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Для описываемого вами случая, предположим, что вы имеет следующую структуру директории:

```
pytest
|-- test.py
|-- nginx.conf
|-- Dockerfile
|-- docker-compose.yaml
```

`Dockerfile` будет иметь следующий вид:

```
# Используем докер образ с python, даем ему имя pytest
FROM python:3.4 as pytest
# Копируем скрипт
ADD test.py .
# Запускем его, скрипт должен сгенерировать рядом с собой файл index.html
RUN python ./test.py

# Используем докер образ с nginx:latest
FROM nginx:latest
# Копируем настройки nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# Копируем из первого контейнера (которому мы дали имя pytest)
# файл index.html
COPY --from=pytest index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Результатом билда данного Dockerfile будет образ nginx с добавленными к нему настройками nginx и вашим файлом index.html (и более ничего лишнего)

Для запуска контейнера будем использовать docker-compose, для жтого составим файл `docker-compose.yaml` со следующим содержимым:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  nginx:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "80:80"
```

В котором:

- "nginx" - имя сервиса (имя которое будет присвоено контейнеру), можно задать любым
- "build: ." - указывает расположение файла Dockerfile для сборки, в данном случае - текущая дериктория
- "ports:" - пробрасывает порты внутри контейра на порты хост машины, порты указываются как "ПОРТ_ХОСТА:ПОРТ_КОНТЕЙНЕРА"

Для запуска сборки образа используйте команду `docker-compose build`.
Для развертывания контейнера используйте команду `docker-compose up -d` - контейнер запустится. Убедится в этом можно выполнив конманду `docker-compose ps`, в терминал выведится приблизительно следующее:

```
       Name                Command          State         Ports       
----------------------------------------------------------------------
pytest_nginx_1   nginx -g daemon off;   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

Файл index.html можно будет просмотреть по адресу http://localhost

В конфигурациях nginx я не силен, но с таким `nginx.conf` у меня все работало:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4086;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       mime.types;
    charset       utf-8;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```